# Generate pcap files from different OS and browser

Tags: wireshark, pcap

I am building a machine learning model for my homework and i can't find the data that i need on the internet so i want to generate pcap files from different OS and browser for example i want to have pcap files from windows using the chrome browser or firefox or edge , pcap files from unix using firefox or chrome , pcap files from Mac using safari or chrome ...

i tried to use wireshark to get my own traffic for exemple i would set my pc with unix or windows on virtuel machine but the problem is that i need a data from diffrent users .

can any one help me with this ?

i looked in the web for the data but i can't find any thing useful .
i tried to generate my own traffic using wireshark but i need to get data from diffrent users .

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do take some time to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for SO. Plus, question has nothing to do with `python` or `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: @desertnaut While this is not a perfect question, you may want to edit your copypasta each time as this question is not asking for a recommendation of the type you're listing; cheers for posting welcome-wagon.

Comment: "i need a data from diffrent users ." => What does this mean? What is the output you've generated so far and how does it differ from your expectations? Please be as specific and granular as possible in [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58482930/edit) your question.

Comment: @RossJacobs the list is not (and cannot be) exhaustive; part of the problem with the post is that there is no explicit *question*, apart from "*can any one help me?*", which is [not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). It *seems* to, at least partially, ask for data in the web. My copypasta may indeed be not very accurate, but I cannot see the reason for customizing it for what seems to be a zero-effort post. The welcome is sincere (did not downvote, as I should), and thanks for chiming in anyway...